# how to implement list iteration in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have written this code

```js
var items = [
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4],
  [5, 6]
];

function listiteration(list, fromrows, torows, col) {

  var newl = list; //making a copy of list
  var iterla = [];
  for (i = fromrows; i <= torows; i++) {
    iterla[i] = [];
    for (j = col; j <= col; j++) {
      iterla[i][j] = newl[i][j];
    }
  }
  return iterla;
}
console.log(listiteration(items, 1, 2, 1));
```

result should be

```
[[4],[6]]
```

but getting

```
[ <1 empty item>, [ <1 empty item>, 4 ], [ <1 empty item>, 6 ] ]
```

how to solve this

Comment: what is the logic of getting `[[4],[6]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the second for loop. Just create a new list, iterate over the rows and use `push` function to add the current rows `col`-th element into the array.

```js
const items = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]];

function listiteration(list, fromRows, toRows, col) {

  const newList = [];
  
  for (let i = fromRows; i <= toRows; i++) {
     newList.push([list[i][col]]);
  }
  
  return newList;
}

const newItems = listiteration(items, 1, 2, 1);
console.log(newItems);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `slice()` and `map()` methods.

```js
var items = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]];
function f(list, start, end, col) {
  return list.slice(start, end + 1).map(e => [e[col]])
}

const result = f(items, 1, 2, 1)
console.log(result)
```

You can also add check for arrays.

```js
var items = [[1, 2], 'a', [5, 6], [1, 2]];
function f(list, start, end, col) {
  return list
    .slice(start, end + 1)
    .map(e => Array.isArray(e) ? [e[col]] : e)
}

const result = f(items, 1, 3, 1)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach

```js
var items = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]];

function listiteration(list, fromrows, torows, col) {
    var ret = [];
    for (var i = fromrows; i <= torows; i++) {
        ret.push(list[i][col]);
    }
    return ret;
}

console.log(listiteration(items, 1, 2, 1));
```

Comment: When you create a snippet, please make sure it runs without error

Answer (score 0):

This would be the solution

```js
var items = [ [1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6] ];

function listiteration(list, start, end, col) {
  var result = [];
  for ( i = start; i <= end; i++ ) {
    result.push( [ list[ i ][ col ] ] )
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(listiteration(items, 1, 2, 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have given you different ways of doing this, and that's great.

But for learning purposes I've fixed the bug in the one you have done.

All you forgot to do was offset the arrays back to zero..

`iterla[i - fromrows][j - col] = newl[i][j];`

Example below..

```js
var items = [
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4],
  [5, 6]
];

function listiteration(list, fromrows, torows, col) {

  var newl = list; //making a copy of list
  var iterla = [];
  for (i = fromrows; i <= torows; i++) {
    iterla[i - fromrows] = [];
    for (j = col; j <= col; j++) {
      iterla[i - fromrows][j - col] = newl[i][j];
    }
  }
  return iterla;
}
console.log(listiteration(items, 1, 2, 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var items = [
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4],
  [5, 6]
];

function listiteration(list, fromrows, torows, col) {
    var newArr    = list.splice(fromrows, torows);
    var newResult =[];
    newArr.map(value=>{
        newResult.push([value[col]]);
    });
    return newResult;
}

console.log(listiteration(items, 1, 2, 1));
```